# taxonomy_term:feed very slow?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created), '%Y%m%d%H') AS node_created_hour,
'taxonomy_term:feed' AS view_name
FROM node node
WHERE (node.status = 1 OR (node.uid = 0 AND 0 <> 0) OR 0 = 1) AND (node.vid IN (
SELECT tn.vid FROM term_node tn
WHERE tn.tid  = 370101
))
ORDER BY node_created_hour DESC
LIMIT 0, 15\G
```

Any ideas or suggestions how can I make this view run faster?

Comment: Are you talking about query works fast and generate output fast?

Comment: @Chirag no its very slow...its brought our site down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
AND (node.vid IN (
SELECT tn.vid FROM term_node tn
WHERE tn.tid  = 370101
))
```

something like this should work:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created), '%Y%m%d%H') AS node_created_hour,
'taxonomy_term:feed' AS view_name
FROM node node
INNER JOIN term_node tn on tn.vid = node.vid
WHERE (node.status = 1 OR (node.uid = 0 AND 0 <> 0) OR 0 = 1) and tn.tid  = 370101     
ORDER BY node_created_hour DESC
LIMIT 0, 15\G
```